# Update Excel table in Python from a second table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have 2 tables(main & new)
Main is the superset of new(has all the values present in new and then some more). The sequence of columns in both main and new is the same (the additional columns in main are at the end).

I have created a key using concatenation of multiple columns present in both. Based on the key, I'll update the main table.

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame(main_sheet.values)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_sheet.values)

# Create primary keys for both DataFrames
main_df['primary_key'] = main_df['col1'].astype(str) + main_df['col2'].astype(str) + main_df['col3'].astype(str)
new_df['primary_key'] = new_df['col1'].astype(str) + new_df['col2'].astype(str) + new_df['col3'].astype(str)

# Operation 1: Find rows present in new but not in main 
missing_in_main_df = new_df[~new_df["primary_key"].isin(main_df["primary_key"])]
```

I want to add the following rows to main(add all the columns values that are common to both and then add static values(text and Excel Formulas) to the columns not present in new)

Comment: did you try `join()`, `concatenate()`, `merge()`?